# Imprimir un ticket muy largo con printDocument

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando imprimir un ticket en una impresora termica, cuando es menos de una hoja el contenido del ticket sale bien, pero cuando el contenido es muy extenso corta en una hoja y el contenido adicional no se imprime.

Tengo estas variables globales

```
        private ArrayList headerLines = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList subHeaderLines = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList totales = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList footerLines = new ArrayList();
        private int maxChar = 40;
        private int maxCharDescription = 15;
        private float topMargin = 3f;
        private string fontName = "Lucida Console";
        private int fontSize = 8;
        private SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        private Image headerImage;
        private int count;
        private int imageHeight;
        private float leftMargin;
        private Font printFont;
        private Graphics gfx;
        private string line;
```

Tengo un método para cada contenido del ticket.

```
     private void DrawHeader()
     {
        foreach (string headerLine in this.headerLines)
        {
            if (headerLine.Length > this.maxChar)
            {
                int startIndex = 0;
                for (int length = headerLine.Length; length > this.maxChar; length -= this.maxChar)
                {
                    this.line = headerLine.Substring(startIndex, this.maxChar);
                    this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                    startIndex += this.maxChar;
                }
                this.line = headerLine;
                this.gfx.DrawString(this.line.Substring(startIndex, this.line.Length - startIndex), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                ++this.count;
                
            }
            else
            {
                this.line = headerLine;
                this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                ++this.count;
            }
        }
    }

private void DrawSubHeader()
        {
            foreach (string subHeaderLine in this.subHeaderLines)
            {
                if (subHeaderLine.Length > this.maxChar)
                {
                    int startIndex = 0;
                    for (int length = subHeaderLine.Length; length > this.maxChar; length -= this.maxChar)
                    {
                        this.line = subHeaderLine;
                        this.gfx.DrawString(this.line.Substring(startIndex, this.maxChar), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                        ++this.count;
                        startIndex += this.maxChar;
                    }
                    this.line = subHeaderLine;
                    this.gfx.DrawString(this.line.Substring(startIndex, this.line.Length - startIndex), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.line = subHeaderLine;
                    this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                    this.line = this.DottedLine();
                    this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                }
            }
            this.DrawEspacio();
        }

private void DrawItems()
        {
            OrderItem orderItem1 = new OrderItem('?');
            this.gfx.DrawString("CANT  DESCRIPCION     PRECIO      TOTAL", this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
            ++this.count;
            this.DrawEspacio();
            foreach (string orderItem2 in this.items)
            {
                this.line = orderItem1.GetItemCantidad(orderItem2);
                this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                this.line = orderItem1.GetItemTotal(orderItem2);
                this.line = this.AlignRightText(this.line.Length) + this.line;
                this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());

                this.line = orderItem1.GetItemPrice(orderItem2);
                this.gfx.DrawString("                      " + this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());

                string itemName = orderItem1.GetItemName(orderItem2);
                this.leftMargin = 0.0f;
                if (itemName.Length > this.maxCharDescription)
                {
                    int startIndex = 0;
                    for (int length = itemName.Length; length > this.maxCharDescription; length -= this.maxCharDescription)
                    {
                        this.line = orderItem1.GetItemName(orderItem2);
                        this.gfx.DrawString("      " + this.line.Substring(startIndex, this.maxCharDescription), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                        ++this.count;
                        startIndex += this.maxCharDescription;
                    }
                    this.line = orderItem1.GetItemName(orderItem2);
                    this.gfx.DrawString("      " + this.line.Substring(startIndex, this.line.Length - startIndex), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.gfx.DrawString("      " + orderItem1.GetItemName(orderItem2), this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                    ++this.count;
                }
            }
            this.leftMargin = 0.0f;
            this.DrawEspacio();
            this.line = this.DottedLine();
            this.gfx.DrawString(this.line, this.printFont, (Brush)this.myBrush, this.leftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
            ++this.count;
            this.DrawEspacio();
        }
```

En el evento PrintPage tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void pr_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            this.gfx = e.Graphics;
            this.DrawHeader();
            this.DrawSubHeader();
            this.DrawItems();
        }
```

Y finalmente tengo un método que invoca la impresión

```
public void PrintTicket(string impresora)
        {
            this.printFont = new Font(this.fontName, (float)this.fontSize, FontStyle.Regular);
            PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = impresora;
            printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pr_PrintPage);
            printDocument.Print();
        }
```

El problema es que cuando los item son muchos no sale todo lo que se agregó para imprimir.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que puede haber un problema con la configuración de la impresora. Primero debes asegurarte de que la impresora esté configurada correctamente para usar la opción PrintDocument en C#. También puedes revisar la documentación de las impresoras térmicas para ver si hay alguna configuración específica para usar el método PrintDocument. Además, también puedes intentar cerrar y volver a abrir la impresora para ver si esto ayuda. Tendríamos que saber la marca de la impresora, los drivers, etc. En realidad solo se me ocurren más preguntas: ¿Si imprimes en la impresora desde el bloc de notas más de una página funciona?. ¿Puedes probar a imprimir página a página?, ¿si imprimes en otra impresora como una de pdf, lo hace bien?

```
p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
    int charsFitted, linesFilled;

    // measure how many characters will fit of the remaining text
    var realsize = e1.Graphics.MeasureString(
        remainingText, 
        font, 
        layoutSize, 
        StringFormat.GenericDefault, 
        out charsFitted,  // this will return what we need
        out linesFilled);

    // take from the remainingText what we're going to print on this page
    var fitsOnPage = remainingText.Substring(0, charsFitted);
    // keep what is not printed on this page 
    remainingText = remainingText.Substring(charsFitted).Trim();

    // print what fits on the page
    e1.Graphics.DrawString(
        fitsOnPage, 
        font, 
        brush, 
        layoutArea);

    // if there is still text left, tell the PrintDocument it needs to call 
    // PrintPage again.
    e1.HasMorePages = remainingText.Length > 0;
};
p.Print();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, desde otra aplicación la impresora imprime bien, desde el programa a una impresora PDF imprime y se corta. La marca de la impresora es una 2connet y también tengo una impresora Epson TermalPrinter TM-U88IV.

Comment: Has probado a poner en el evento de impresión y le indicas el número de páginas?, ver ejemplo arriba. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979794/how-to-print-a-long-string-into-multiple-pages-in-c-sharp

Comment: ¿has podido probar si con HasMorePages = True imprime el resto?

Comment: Como tengo un metodo para cada parte del recibo la propuesta que me das tendría que almacenar todo el texto en un único string e imprimirlo, pero basado en como tengo estructurado el código no habría una manera para poder resolver mi problema?

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta ya es antigua pero tal vez a los nuevos les sirva y ya que no he encontrado ninguna respuesta al respecto, les comparto..
Cuando no imprime el ticket largo completo es porque se Codificó que lo imprima hasta cierto punto o cierta medida, lo cual siempre va a respetar siendo tal vez de la siguiente manera.

`PaperZise ps = new PaperZise("Ticket,300,600")`

El largo del Ticket es 600 por lo tanto siempre será su limite de impresión y para cambiar ese límite a mas largo debe ser de la siguiente manera.

```
PaperZize ps = default;
```

default toma el largo predefinido en el software de la impresora, de hecho que cada impresora tiene su límite, solo debes asegurarte que tenga seleccionada la configuración mas larga..